# Jquery Clone Elements With Dynamic Content

Tags: jquery, dynamic

I am so stuck here! I have dynamically created elements inside a div that I need to make a "copy" of, or more like a "second version" of that element. The main function with this is to create a quiz with questions and answers, but I need to make it possible to create multiple questions and answers in one quiz.

Here is the Jquery:

```
    var QuestionCreator = "QuestionCreator" + x++;
    $(".modal-body-createquiz").html("<div id='QuestionCreator'><fieldset><div class='row-fluid'><div class='span12'><div class='control-group'><label>Your Question:</label><div class='controls'><input type='text' class='input-fluid' id='NewQuizQuestion'></div></div></div><legend>Answers:</legend><div class='control-group'><label class='checkbox pull-right'><input type='checkbox' id='NewQuizRemoveAlts'> Remove Alternatives</label></div><div class='NewQuizNotice'></div><div class='NewQuizAnswersGroup'></div><a href='#' id='addNewAltRadio' class='btn pull-right'><i class='fa-icon-plus-sign'></i> Create new alternative</a></div></fieldset></div>").hide().fadeIn('slow');

    var newAnswerAlt = "appendAnswerAltRadio" + i++;
    $("<div><div class='controls'><input type='text' class='answerAltRadiobtn' data-type='answer' class='input-fluid' name='txtAnswer"+ n++ +"'> <label class='checkbox'><input type='checkbox' id='QuizCheckbox"+ c++ +"'> Correct Answer</label></div></div>").attr({id: newAnswerAlt, class: ''}).prependTo(".NewQuizAnswersGroup").hide().fadeIn('slow');
    });
    $(this).on('click', '#addNewAltRadio', function () {
    var newAnswerAlt = "appendAnswerAltRadio" + i++;
    $("<div><div class='controls'><input type='text' class='answerAltRadiobtn' data-type='answer' class='input-fluid' name='txtAnswer"+ n++ +"'> <label class='checkbox'><input type='checkbox' id='QuizCheckbox"+ c++ +"'> Correct Answer</label></div></div>").attr({id: newAnswerAlt, class: ''}).prependTo(".NewQuizAnswersGroup").hide().fadeIn('slow');
    });
```

And here I'm trying to make a clone of the created element, but this need to be unique, so what happens in one clone, doesn't affect the others. So it's like "starting from scratch" for each newly created clone.

```
    $("#addNewQuizCreateQuestion").click(function() {
    $("#QuestionCreator").clone().appendTo(".modal-body-createquiz");
    });
```

Does anyone have a hint on what to do here?

Or you need more code to get the picture?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: And also make it possible to "switch" back and forward between the created elements

Comment: can u post a jsfiddle?

Comment: your selectors like `.NewQuizAnswersGroup` could cause problems once you clone the eleemnt

Comment: I made a http://jsfiddle.net/QbbFB/ but there it doesn't work to add new alternatives. Maybe it doesn't "say so much.."

Comment: So I need to make selector like `.NewQuizAnswersGroup` unique when I clone them?

Answer (score 1):

Hope This would help you.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arjuncc/QbbFB/5/)

The logic I have used here is like, I am creating the clone of your first div that is "QuestionCreator1". I have kept a hidden field to save the current ID (the incrementing part). I used the [last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/) method and your class name "QuestionCreator", to get the last element. Then updated its(id of the last element) ID after cloning it from "QuestionCreator1".

```
 $("#addNewQuizCreateQuestion").click(function() {
             var currentId=$("#currentId").val();
            var currentIdInt=parseInt(currentId);
            currentIdInt++;
            $("#currentId").val(currentIdInt);
        $("#QuestionCreator1").clone().appendTo(".modal-body-createquiz");
            $(".QuestionCreator").last().attr("id","QuestionCreator"+currentIdInt);
        });
```

Comment: please let me know, if more clarification needed

Comment: Thanks! But it's still creating a 100% clone of the old #QuestionCreator so if I add "more alternatives" to the first Question, it adds more on the second aswell

Comment: @Kim, you are creating a clone, of the prev element. So u 'll be getting a copy of the same. Could you explain your requirement a little bit more?

Comment: Okey, sorry if I wasn't clear with my question :) What I would like to achive is this. 1.) Create the #QuestionCreator which contains the first question in a quiz. Where you can add as many alternatives you'd like. 2.) Click on #addNewQuizCreateQuestion to create a new question. Not a clone of #QuestionCreator but with the same features. So here you can create question 2 in the quiz. And add more questions the same way. And also have the ability to "zap" between question 1 and 2, 3 etc.

Comment: So if I append a new "alternative" to the quiz, it should append to the new #QuestionCreator and also in some way identify each question with for example an ID so I can get them later.

Comment: Maybe it's a lot to ask for but right now I'm empty of ideas :)

Comment: Yes man! Soon getting there! Now it's creating new questions correctly! But when I append new "alternatives" it appends to #NewQuizAnswersGroup inside every #QuestionCreator do I need to make the #NewQuizAnswersGroup unique for every new question? And how do I know where to append the new "alternatives" if I don't know the unique ID?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29098/discussion-between-arjuncc-and-kim)

Comment: Arjuncc, are you still around?